# I need a formula that averages two dates without being affected by other dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an excel workbook that contains a lot of columns side by side. In each column there are two dates side by side that I want to average. I have about 7 columns all containing two dates that need to be averaged. 
I used the formula =AVERAGE(27:27) thinking that it would average the two dates inside each column separately, but it didn't. It took all the 14 dates (7 columns x 2 dates per column) and averaged them all together. 
I need a formula that averages all the dates separately per column without the other dates affecting each other.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this? I'm going to be using a lot more columns inside the workbook so I need a formula that I don't have to edit every time I add a column.
To make it clear, my dates are horizontal from one another, so when I say column, I mean two columns together.

Comment: This might be clearer if you add a screenshot.  What do you mean by averaging dates?  If you average Nov 3 and Nov 4, what do you get?  Are you saying you want to average pairs of something (the average of two values), and those 2 values are contained within the same cell?  If so, what does the cell look like and what is the possible range of stuff that needs to be dealt with?  Are you saying you also want to replicate this action over a range?  If so, to create a collection of averaged pairs?  Where do the results go?  How do columns and rows relate?

Comment: the formula you use `=AVERAGE(27:27)` will average all numbers in row 27. Is that what you want to do? If not, just specify which cells to average.

Comment: The dates are in row 27, but I want each column to average it's two dates separately from the other columns dates. But I don't know how to do that because all the dates in each column are on row 27? So how can I average each columns dates separately?

Comment: It's like this: 10/17/2019 10/22/2019, those two are on row 27 and in a columns of there own. I need those to be averaged, but there are 12 more dates in six columns that are on row 27.

Comment: I want to average the two cells in each column. Right now, I have 7 columns. I need to average the two dates in each column without it being affected by the other columns dates.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add relevant information instead of adding it in comments. It would be best to post sample data and the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Q&A above, it sounds like each cell (at a given row and column) contains two dates.  Per the description, that's the only way that one row and 7 columns contain 14 dates in total.

In this case, the formulas below assume that the row is 27 and the columns are A through G.  I am also assuming that the two dates in each cell are separated by a line feed (aka ALT+Enter in the cell which is ASCII code 10, but this can easily be substituted for another character, such as a space).

There are 3 steps to doing this, parsing out the two dates, then averaging them.

### Getting the 1st date:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A27,SEARCH(CHAR(10),A27,1)-1))
```

Explanation from the inside out:

- `SEARCH` = find the position of the first instance of a character, in this case line feed or `CHAR(10)`.
- `LEFT` = extract the part of the string to the left of the given position (aka, to the left of the line feed).
- `DATEVALUE` = convert the extracted string to a date.

### Getting the 2nd date:

```
=RIGHT(A27,LEN(A27)-SEARCH(CHAR(10),A27))
```

`RIGHT` starts at the right-side of the string and returns the specified number of characters.  Here, we ask for the number of remaining characters from the length, based on the position of the line feed.

### Putting it all together:

```
=AVERAGE(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A27,SEARCH(CHAR(10),A27,1)-1)),RIGHT(A27,LEN(A27)-SEARCH(CHAR(10),A27)))
```

This averages the value in 1 column.  You can change the cell (from A27 to B27, C27, D27, etc.) to average the remaining cells.

The screenshot below shows what I assumed the input data looks like (and the results of the final formula are on row 29).

[image: Image of sample dates and final results]

**EDIT1:** A typo and I wanted to point out that if the dates are separated by another character, use the decimal value from [this table](http://www.asciitable.com/) in the `CHAR` part of the formula.

**EDIT2:** Fixed formula for getting the 2nd date reliably, regardless of length.

**EDIT3:** As a reference, here are the formulas in columns A and B together, so you can see what is changing:

```
=AVERAGE(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A27,SEARCH(CHAR(10),A27,1)-1)),RIGHT(A27,LEN(A27)-SEARCH(CHAR(10),A27)))
=AVERAGE(DATEVALUE(LEFT(B27,SEARCH(CHAR(10),B27,1)-1)),RIGHT(B27,LEN(B27)-SEARCH(CHAR(10),B27)))
```

Comment: If @zakaluka's anwer is not what you are looking for, please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1498729/edit) to clarify it.

Comment: @zankaluka, thanks for the help! But, my two dates are horizontal to each other, not vertical. Will the formula still work?

Comment: Also, do I  have to enter this formula in every cell, or just one and it will work for all cells?

Comment: I just tried this formula and it didn't work. My dates are horizontal and not stacked like you had yours. Is there a formula that will work for that?

Comment: @John, if your dates are separated by a space, replace the text that says `CHAR(10)` with `CHAR(32)`.

The new, final formula would be:

`=AVERAGE(DATEVALUE(LEFT(A27,SEARCH(CHAR(32),A27,1)-1)),RIGHT(A27,LEN(A27)-SEARCH(CHAR(32),A27)))`

Comment: @John, you have to put the formula into 1 cell per column for which you want the average.  Since you have 7 columns, you need 7 formulas, but they are ALL different because each formula points to a different column.  In my original answer, in section "Edit3", see how the Cell changes from `A27` to `B27`.  Put the correct formula into Cell `A29`, then drag it across using the fill handle.  See the section "To use the fill handle" on [this page](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/excel2013/cell-basics/1/) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I figured it out.